# Most efficient way of displaying latest user activity in your site? PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, logging, user-activity

I'd think to make a new table (logs_table) and track the activity there. So the only query I'd have to run is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM logs_table
```

and I'll be ok. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Pro hint: Try not to name your tables `something_table`. It's like naming a variable `$name_variable` or your child `Alex-child`. We know it's a table. You can simply call it `logs` or even `log_entries`.

Comment: it was an example, but anyways thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Not really, best shot is to save data in DB, however I'd be careful with the structure and the age of records before you delete them, so you don't overload the DB and slow down the site.